# Calling method with in same jsp page

Tags: jsp, validation, methods

I have a **jsp** page where i want to submit some values from user. So i have created a form.
Now i want to perform some validation check before letting it pass to servlet which would be responsible for performing business logic. 
So, now i want that i should call a `validate()` which would be within this jsp only, and this `validate()` will perform some check and if successful then pass the control to servlet.

I know we can write java code in jsp using scriptlet so i can make `validate()`, but how to pass control from form action to validate method with the parameter is issue for me.

Your suggestion would be helpful and if there exist a better way that is also good.

```
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.Out"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%! String name = new String("jsp");
        %>

    <form action="FirstJSP.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="regid"> <input type="text"
            name="studentName"> <input type="text" name="class">
        <input type="text" name="section"> <input type="text"
            name="hindi"> <input type="text" name="english"> <input
            type="text" name="maths"> <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to validate, might I suggest using JavaScript?

Comment: Learn servlets before it's too late: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSP is executing on the server BEFORE it gets to the user. By the time it gets to the browser, it is just HTML. If you want to do validation prior to the servlet getting the form submission, you would need to do that in JavaScript in the browser. Add a click handler to your submit button that does the validation and cancels the submit if there are problems.

However, note that it is bad practice to rely solely on client-side validations -- if you are doing a POST, you should be validating the data on the server too.

Comment: I just wanted to separate business part from UI part, that is why i thought making a validation check would be better option. Also could you please share a little code snippet for javascript. I am updating the  question, and adding jsp file to it